# How to read multiple JSON objects from a single file in Java?

Tags: java, json, object

I have multiple JSON objects stored in the file, e.g. `Test.json`

The problem comes when I try to read from that file, it does not let me read multiple json objects. I want to read all objects from the file.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: JSON does not specify a sequence of values (other then putting them into an array). So this is always implementation dependent. Are the values somehow separated on the file?

Comment: I'd try to use Decorator pattern for IO-a wrapper which implements java.io.Reader and stores a reference to another Reader (to a delegate).The decorator will add additional chars to present the sequence of read objects as a JSON array,for example. When you call read first time,your decorator adds '[' to the beginning,before the content read from the delegate,when the delegate reads the last chars,the decorator adds ']' to the end to finish the array.When the decorator finds a delimiter between your objects in chars read from the delegate,it replaces the delimiter by ',' between the objects

Comment: ...Or just read and parse the file part by part. And just FYI  - a streaming parser which can be used easily for buffering reading, even byte by byte https://github.com/anatolygudkov/green-jelly

Answer (score -1):

Try using `JSONArray`

```
JSONArray JArray = new JSONArray(JSON_FILE_AS_STRING);
```

then you can loop through the objects

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
jObj = JArray.getJSONObject(i);
```